# FTDI d2xx android communication

Tags: android, usb, usbserial, ftdi

I've been trying to use TN_134 FTDI Android D2XX Driver and the test application, and failed miserably. 
LogCat tells me that it unable to load the .jni file and the app crashes every time it tries to...
The .jni library cannot be loaded, because my device is not rooted (and I don't intend to root it). 
Is there any way to bypass this, using the same chip-set? Is there a way to integrate the .jni code in the test app code, so that the library file won't be needed? I'm open to any suggestions that don't involve rooting the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, i just Corrected the location of the JNI in the code(D2xx class) to the proper one i.e from the default location to "/data/data/com.ftdi.d2xx/lib/libftd2xx-jni.so".

By the way the driver you are using needs root access. A new driver has been released by FTDI which they say doesn't require root access. Just check that out from their website [FTDI Android D2xx Driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm)

Comment: I have read() problem with official drivers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518214/official-ftdi-android-drivers-read-is-not-working